# Unable to Import Digital Photos

Tags: shotwell

I am unable to import digital photos in Ubuntu 12.04.

When I plug in my camera (Canon EOS Rebel Tii) it is immediately recognized, but I am unable to download any photos.  So far I have tried:

1. Using Shotwell: Shotwell almost immedately hangs after I hit "import", and eventually it crashes.
2. Using DarkTable: DarkTable hangs when I hit "import".
3. Using the Ubuntu GUI file viewer: the camera is recognized, but any attempt to open the flash drive's internal folders crashes the file viewer

I am certain the camera is working fine because I can easily download photos on a friend's Mac. Does anyone have any tips?  I have a lot of wedding photos on my camera right now and people are getting quite anxious to see them.

Comment: I am having the same problem as these people: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/995886
Any work around would be great, these are wedding photos and people are not going to be patient with me.

Comment: have you tried the terminal? cp -r /media ~/

Comment: I did try that, yeah.  The folder is completely empty.

Comment: Having the same problem as the original poster, I have added all the information I could on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/995886. It would be great if we could figure this one out, as it is a blocker issue for camera usage with Ubuntu 12.04. I'll provide all the information I can!

Comment: @wild_oscar I contacted all the Linux gurus I know and have spent non-trivial amounts of time trying to solve the problem. I have been completely unsuccessful. I only chose the below 'use a card reader' solution because I gave up.
I'd be happy to dig through source code and try and fix the issue, but I can't tell what the issue is on any technical level.
Tell me if you make any progress.

Comment: @thejollysin card readers actually work and do not discharge your camera batteries

Comment: the original issue was due the [gphoto component of gvfs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/995886/comments/16). The issue was fixed. If you have new issues please submit them to LaunchPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried popping out the memory card and using an external card reader? It sounds like your camera may not be using the mass-storage-device drivers correctly.

Comment: I don't have an external card reader, no.  I might try that, or just download them on a friend's computer.  Since my original post, I found this was a bug on the official bugs list: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/995886 And if I can't find a good work around, it will seriously slow me down.  For now, I guess, maybe an external card reader is the solution.

Comment: I've had enough issues with Windows and Linux connecting cameras directly with USB that I've just been using card readers for several years. They are cheap ($10-$15) at any big box store and aren't plagued with the usual fuss of cameras, because they always just show up as a mass storage device.

Comment: Okay, after much effort and searching, I have given up and bought a card reader.  Sad, really.  I had such high hopes for Ubuntu.